# QuickFIX marketdatarequest after disconnect

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

Im using quickfix. I start session and send MarketDataRequest, it works fine, but after the disconnect happened and quickfix session reconnected, i cant get any market data anymore. Server does not respond on my MarketDataRequests at all. Only session recreation fixes this issue.

How is that could be fixed? What should i do after reconnection to receive market data?

Comment: What is in your message log?  The answer should be in there.  Did your counterparty reject the MDRequest?

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing in the log. Just no any responce or reject. I get reject only if i send invalid message.

Comment: This might be a question for your counterparty's support, then.  Also check their interface's documentation; maybe there's a quirk to their system that you missed.

Comment: what do you mean by "server does not respond" ? probably it does respond but you somehow didn't catch the response. I would suggest to install wireshark or another sniffer and check what happening.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to get market data after disconnection is like trying to talk on the phone after you've hung up.  It's impossible; the communication channel is gone!

(Is it possible you've left some important details out of your question?)

Comment: I've edited my post, but i thought that it's obvious that i mean that i was reconnected after the disconnect. And after this reconnect i cant get responce on my marketdatarequest. But heartbeats works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your log should show the logon message (35=A) as well as the attempt to sync or reset the sequence numbers (35=4) depending on your FIX engine configuration.

Are you not seeing the logon or logoff (35=5) messages?

Try issuing a TestRequest (35=1), if you are disconnected then it looks like your sequence numbers are out of sync.